# Convert a dataframe column of strings to individual lists

Tags: python, pandas

dataframe:

```
col0    col1                col2
user1   {'asdf','defa'}     {'zxvc','vbcz'}
user2   {'asdff','defadg'}  {'zxdfc','vadz'}
dtype: object

in: type(df.col1[0])
out: str
```

Trying to convert the rows (which are strings) in col1 and col2 to individual lists (in separate columns; don't want to combine these two columns in to one list).

I keep getting errors when trying to use json.load or json.loads or ast.literal_eval:

```
df.col1.apply(ast.literal_eval)
error: unknown line 1

df.col1.apply(json.loads)
works but nothing seems to have changed

df.col1.apply(json.load)
error: str object has no attribute 'read'; which is why i tried json.loads
```

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message(s), as well as a [mcve].** Where does this data come from, how does it end up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval
df.applymap(lambda c: list(literal_eval(c)))
```

output:

[image]

if you have more columns with different datatypes you could use:

```
df.col1 = df.col1.apply(lambda c: list(literal_eval(c)))
df.col2 = df.col2.apply(lambda c: list(literal_eval(c)))
```

Comment: i don't think this will work if there are additional columns - which i apologize, there are, i didn't add the other columns in the dataframe. I did now though

Comment: @max what about now ?

Comment: oh my god it worked. after running the 2 lines at the bottom of your comment. thank you so much.
type(df.col1[0]) is a list now